# Fizzler and QuerySelectorAll

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've found [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) as html parser and jQuery like selector . But seems visual studio can not resolve `QuerySelectorAll` method.

here is my code :

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);
var c = document.QuerySelectorAll('div');
```

did I miss any references ?

**EDIT :** 
after some search I found this code for using Fizzler

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
const string search = "td";
SelectorGenerator<HtmlNode> selectorGenerator1 = new SelectorGenerator<HtmlNode>(new HtmlNodeOps());
HumanReadableSelectorGenerator selectorGenerator2 = new HumanReadableSelectorGenerator();
Parser.Parse(search, new SelectorGeneratorTee(selectorGenerator1, selectorGenerator2));
var c =  selectorGenerator1.Selector(Enumerable.Repeat(doc.DocumentNode, 1)).ToList();
```

I'm still looking for find good answer for my question.

Comment: @IanNewson , `QuerySelectorAll` gets `XmlNode` as static parameter , but `type` of `document.DocumentNode` is `HtmlNode` !!!!

Answer (score 6):

Probably this:

```
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

Also give a shot to CsQuery, my C# jQuery port: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

```
var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl(url);
var c = dom["div"];
```

.. plus everything you're used to from jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but that works:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;

var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load("some-url");
var c = document.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("div");
```

`QuerySelectorAll` is an extension method for the `HtmlNode` type, but you were trying to use it over a `HtmlDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably missing reference to `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack`

I would recommend adding this nuget package. [Fizzler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/1.0.0)

```
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
using HtmlAgilityPack;    
using HtmlDoc = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
```

and then you can use it like

```
var html = new HtmlDoc();
html.LoadHtml(HtmlText);

// Fizzler for HtmlAgilityPack is implemented as the 
// QuerySelectorAll extension method on HtmlNode

var document = html.DocumentNode;

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll(".content");
```

Answer (score 0):

If using QuerySelectorAll you should creat an array to check if div is not null and then you can use queryselector

```
 HtmlNode[] test= html.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("div.hlogo").ToArray();
      for (int rowcounter = 0; rowcounter < test.Count(); rowcounter++)
       {
      var logoname = test[rowcounter].QuerySelector("a").InnerText;    
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it. Maybe you have done same mistake of mine. I had defined assemblies in a few config files. When i deleted all and install packages back again there had been working well.

- Uninstall  `Fizzler`, `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` in the nuget manager.
- Delete all these dll from bin and debug folder.
- Delete all dependency assemblies which about these dll in appconfig and webconfig
- Install last version of `Fizzler` and `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` packages in the manage nuget packages.

  After that you can use `QuerySelectorAll` and other methods without error wherever you want.

Do not install HtmlAgilityPack only by itself. When you install Fizzler, HtmlAgilityPack will installed automaticly.